# Does unsubscribing from an email actually remove my details?

Tags: privacy, email

I get quite a few emails from valid companies and organisations in my inbox. Unfortunately most of these emails are marketing-type emails which don't have any value for me. As a result I tend to unsubscribe these emails often. My question is this - When I click unsubscribe, are my details removed from the sender's database/address book? If a database is being used, are my records put into a "soft-delete" status? Is there a general consensus for what action is normally taken when I choose to unsubscribe?

Comment: We can't know how a unknown entity manages its records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in the EU, then simply unsubscribing from communication will likely **not** remove any personal information. By law they are still allowed to store any personal information you gave including your email address and it is likely that they are.

If you want your personal information to be forgotten you would have to make a specific request for that to take place under your "right to be forgotten". This is typically done by simply sending a request along those lines to their privacy contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really be sure about what happens when you unsubscribe.

---

You could use a unique e-mail for each subscription (yourname+purpose@gmail.com for example) thus if you receive e-mails to this address after you have unsubscribed, it may mean your address has been shared. However, some registration forms don't really handle this "+something" with their email validation regex, and others may simply strip this part...

Sometimes, emails you'll receive will contain an "unsubscribe" link whose purpose is only to validate that your e-mail address exists and is valid.

Comment: The first line is the only part relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's implementation dependent, but I think we can safely assume that *legitimate* email marketing companies work in a sensible manner, and therefore:

> When I click unsubscribe, are my details removed from the sender's database/address book?

Highly unlikely.

> If a database is being used, are my records put into a "soft-delete" status?

Highly unlikely.

> Is there a general consensus for what action is normally taken when I choose to unsubscribe?

Probably, Yes. The most common (and practical) scenario would be that your email address is preserved in the database with the "Unsubscribed" flag set. Since most marketing companies obtain lists of email addresses from third parties, they need to retain your email address in their database so that the next time they come across your address you will remain unsubscribed. (If they deleted you from their records you would likely just show up again in another future email dump and they'd start spamming you again.)